# How to modify values in a list

Tags: r, list, if-statement, lapply

I have a list:

```
xxx

[[1]]
[1] 1899   99   99   97   97   97   97   97

[[2]]
[1] 86 86 86 86 86 86 86

[[3]]
 [1] 1897   97   97   97   97   97   97   97   97   97

[[4]]
[1] 3 3 3 3

[[5]]
 [1] 1883   83   83   83   83   83   83   83   83   83
```

`Dput:`

```
list(c(1899L, 99L, 99L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 97L), c(86L, 86L, 
86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L), c(1897L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 
97L, 97L, 97L), c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), c(1883L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 
83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L))
```

I then choose the most frequent value in each list element, and repeat that value by the length of the list element:

```
xxxh=lapply(xxx,function(x) {

  a=max(rle(sort(x))[[1]])

  b=rle(sort(x))[[2]][which(rle(sort(x))[[1]]==a)]

  hh=rep(b,length(x))

  return(hh)

})
```

I get a warning `"In max(rle(sort(x))[[1]]) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf"`

The result is

```
xxxh
[[1]]
[1] 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97

[[2]]
[1] 86 86 86 86 86 86 86

[[3]]
 [1] 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97

[[4]]
[1] 3 3 3 3

[[5]]
 [1] 83 83 83 83 83 83 83 83 83 83
```

I then try to `paste` those values in the list elements above with either `18` or `190` depending on the `nchar` of the first element of each list element:

```
xxxm=lapply(xxxh,function(x) {

  kk=x[1]


  if(nchar(kk==0)) {   kk<-0 }

  else {

  if (nchar(kk)==1) {as.numeric(paste(190,kk,sep=""))} else {

  if (nchar(kk)==2) as.numeric(paste(18,kk,sep=""))}}

}

    )
```

But I only get `zeros`...

```
xxxm
[[1]]
[1] 0

[[2]]
[1] 0

[[3]]
[1] 0

[[4]]
[1] 0

[[5]]
[1] 0
```

I would like to get:

```
xxxm
[[1]]
[1] 1897

[[2]]
[1] 1896

[[3]]
[1] 1897

[[4]]
[1] 1903

[[5]]
[1] 1883
```

What am I doing wrong?:(

Best Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first `if(nchar(kk==0))` should be `if(nchar(kk)==0)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify the process greatly down to two lines:

Use `lapply` with `table` and `which.max` to get the modes. (*statistical modes, not R-language modes*)
Then use `ifelse` to paste accordingly, using the condition if the value is less than 10

```
# find the most frequent value, using `table` & `which.max` 
mode.mylist <- lapply(mylist, function(x) names(which.max(table(x))))

# paste values as needed.  No need to count characters. Instead check if the value is less than 10. (R coerces to numeric)
ifelse(mode.mylist < 10, paste0("190", mode.mylist), paste0("18", mode.mylist))

[1] "1897" "1886" "1897" "1903" "1883"
```

---

Where `mylist` is your starting list, eg:

```
mylist <- list(c(1899L, 99L, 99L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 97L), c(86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L), c(1897L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 97L), c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), c(1883L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this too

```
xxxm <- lapply(xxx,
               function(x) rep(which.max(tabulate(x)), length(x)))

lapply(xxxm, function(x)
       as.numeric(paste0(c(190, 18)[nchar(unique(x))], unique(x))))


[[1]]
[1] 1897

[[2]]
[1] 1886

[[3]]
[1] 1897

[[4]]
[1] 1903

[[5]]
[1] 1883
```

Comment: @user1665355, a nice way of saying "nice solution" is to up-vote.